# Lucene query object and search

Tags: java, lucene

I am upgrading from Lucene 3.6 to 5.3.0, but the search doesn't want to take my parameters when using 5.3.0.

This works in 3.6:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.open(directory));
SimpleAnalyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "contents",
                analyzer);
TopDocs topDocs = null;
Query query = parser.parse(queryString);
topDocs = searcher.search(query, 1000);
```

But in 5.3, the compiler is asking me to use SrndQuery, but I still get an error on the searcher.search method:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(directory));
Analyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser();
TopDocs topDocs = null;

SrndQuery query = QueryParser.parse(queryString);
topDocs = searcher.search(query, 1000);//**The method search(Query, int) in the type IndexSearcher is not applicable for the arguments (SrndQuery, int)**
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any ideas?

P.S. I am upgrading because I am not able to get Highlighted text from some PDFs I recently indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It bears stating that you are using the Surround query parser, rather than the standard query parser (if you are intending to use the standard parser, you are importing the wrong one).

The problem you are running into is that a `SrndQuery` isn't really a lucene query, so you can't just run it into the searcher and get results.  You need to transform it into lucene query to search with it.  This is done via the [`SrndQuery.makeLuceneQueryField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/surround/query/SrndQuery.html#makeLuceneQueryField(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.queryparser.surround.query.BasicQueryFactory)) method. You'll need to create a [`BasicQueryFactory`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/surround/query/BasicQueryFactory.html) to pass into it, but they are easy to construct:

```
SrndQuery query = QueryParser.parse(queryString);
BasicQueryFactory factory = new BasicQueryFactory(1000 /*maxBasicQueries*/);
Query luceneQuery = query.makeLuceneQueryField("myDefaultField", factory);
topDocs = searcher.search(luceneQuery, 1000);
```

---

*Somewhat Tangential Note:* I kinda wondered if you should keep the `BasicQueryFactory` around, rather than creating a new one for every search, but appears to be unnecessary.  Definitely nothing expensive going on in the ctor, and it looks like solr's `SurroundQParserPlugin` constructs a new one for each query it parses, so doing that should be fine.

Comment: +femtoRgon this code is a part of a web based search, so I didnt bother to reuse, since it's a single request at a time. I'll try your suggestions now.

Comment: +femtoRgon that worked, thanks. Thanks for the explanation.